# Node.js cfenv causes TypeError on localhost

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

In my app.js, the line "var cfenv = require 'cfenv';" causes

```
path.js:8
    throw new TypeError('Path must be a string. Received ' +
    ^

TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
at assertPath (path.js:8:11)
at Object.posix.join (path.js:479:5)
at getPortsFile (/Users/user1/Dev/src/bluemix/dirt/node_modules/ports/index.js:62:15)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user1/Dev/src/bluemix/dirt/node_modules/ports/index.js:13:29)
at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
at require (module.js:385:17)
```

the module 'cfenv' is installed in the local node_modules and the app works on Bluemix.

Here's the package.json, but the versions don't seem to impact it. this only recently started to cause errors, but I cannot trace the origin...

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "4.12.4",
    "cfenv": "1.0.3"
},
"repository": {},
"engines": {
    "node": "0.12.x"
}
```

Comment: what is the version of node.js you have installed locally?

Comment: just to clarify, that should be "var cfenv = require ('cfenv');", your parentheses are missing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include your cfenv package, for example using the following code:

> var cfenv = require ("cfenv");

From your source I see that you aren't using the correct syntax require('package')

> var cfenv = require 'cfenv';

you can see that round brackets are missing.